# UITableViewCell changes from 2.1 to 3.0 - Duplicate Cells

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell that I create for a UITableView. Let's say I have 26 cells (letters of the alphabet). In SDK 2.1 I load the first six cells, A->F, then scroll down and it loads the next six cells (G->L).

In SDK 3.0 I load the first six cells, A->F, then scroll, it reloads the first six cells again (A->F), instead of cells (G->L) even though the data model has changed.

Does anyone know what changes in SDK 3.0 affected the layout of UITableViewCell in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only changes in UITableViewCell in the 3.0 SDK I know of are the transition to allow complete access to the internal UILabel and UIImageView.

If setup correctly, cells should never have to reload completely (be released and re-allocated). Make sure you are using the reuseWithIdentifier methods in the SDK, and it will recycle your premade cell and just swap out content.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I'll check.